# Using Javascript to do comparison of user inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code that is using 3 columns to check for difference in input values.
The third column difference in my view is generated fine but while viewing it the table is not displaying it.

What is want to do is to compare base text with new text and thrid text input enteries and display the changes to user in inline or side by side format

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
    <title>jsdifflib demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="diffview.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="diffview.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="difflib.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Sans-Serif,serif;
}
h2 {
    margin: 0.5em 0 0.1em;
    text-align: center;
}
.top {
    text-align: center;
}
.textInput {
    display: block;
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
}
textarea {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
}
label:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.spacer {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.viewType {
    font-size: 16px;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
}
#diffoutput {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function diffUsingJS(viewType) {
    "use strict";
    var byId = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); },
        base = difflib.stringAsLines(byId("baseText").value),
        newtxt = difflib.stringAsLines(byId("newText").value),
            thirdText = difflib.stringAsLines(byId("3rdText").value),
        sm = new difflib.SequenceMatcher(base, newtxt, thirdText),
        opcodes = sm.get_opcodes(),
        diffoutputdiv = byId("diffoutput"),
        contextSize = byId("contextSize").value;

    diffoutputdiv.innerHTML = "";
    contextSize = contextSize || null;

    diffoutputdiv.appendChild(diffview.buildView({
        baseTextLines: base,
        newTextLines: newtxt,
        thirdTextLines: thirdText,
        opcodes: opcodes,
        baseTextName: "Base Text",
        newTextName: "New Text",
        thirdTextName: "Third Text",
        contextSize: contextSize,
        viewType: viewType
    }));
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <strong>Context size (optional):</strong> <input type="text" id="contextSize" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="textInput">
        <h2>Base Text</h2>
        <textarea id="baseText" >a</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="textInput spacer">
        <h2>New Text</h2>
        <textarea id="newText">b</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="textInput spacer">
        <h2>3rd Text</h2>
        <textarea id="3rdText">c</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="viewType">
        <input type="radio" name="_viewtype" id="sidebyside" onclick="diffUsingJS(0);" /> <label for="sidebyside">Side by Side Diff</label>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="_viewtype" id="inline" onclick="diffUsingJS(1);" /> <label for="inline">Inline Diff</label>
    </div>
    <div id="diffoutput"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**diffview.js**

```
var diffview = {

        /**
         * Builds and returns a visual diff view.  The single parameter, `params', should contain
         * the following values:
         *
         * - baseTextLines: the array of strings that was used as the base text input to SequenceMatcher
         * - newTextLines: the array of strings that was used as the new text input to SequenceMatcher
         * - opcodes: the array of arrays returned by SequenceMatcher.get_opcodes()
         * - baseTextName: the title to be displayed above the base text listing in the diff view; defaults
         *     to "Base Text"
         * - newTextName: the title to be displayed above the new text listing in the diff view; defaults
         *     to "New Text"
         * - contextSize: the number of lines of context to show around differences; by default, all lines
         *     are shown
         * - viewType: if 0, a side-by-side diff view is generated (default); if 1, an inline diff view is
         *     generated
         */
        buildView: function (params) {
            var baseTextLines = params.baseTextLines;
            var newTextLines = params.newTextLines;
            var thirdTextLines = params.thirdTextLines;
            var opcodes = params.opcodes;
            var baseTextName = params.baseTextName ? params.baseTextName : "Base Text";
            var newTextName = params.newTextName ? params.newTextName : "New Text";
            var thirdTextName = params.thirdTextName ? params.thirdTextName: "Third Text"
            var contextSize = params.contextSize;
            var inline = (params.viewType == 0 || params.viewType == 1) ? params.viewType : 0;

            if (baseTextLines == null)
                throw "Cannot build diff view; baseTextLines is not defined.";
            if (newTextLines == null)
                throw "Cannot build diff view; newTextLines is not defined.";
            if (thirdTextLines == null)
                throw "Cannot build diff view; thirdTextLines is not defined.";
            if (!opcodes)
                throw "Canno build diff view; opcodes is not defined.";

            function celt (name, clazz) {
                var e = document.createElement(name);
                e.className = clazz;
                return e;
            }

            function telt (name, text) {
                var e = document.createElement(name);
                e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
                return e;
            }

            function ctelt (name, clazz, text) {
                var e = document.createElement(name);
                e.className = clazz;
                e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
                return e;
            }

            var tdata = document.createElement("thead");
            var node = document.createElement("tr");
            tdata.appendChild(node);
            if (inline) {
                node.appendChild(document.createElement("th"));
                node.appendChild(document.createElement("th"));
                node.appendChild(ctelt("th", "texttitle", baseTextName + " vs. " + newTextName + " vs. " + thirdTextName));
            } else {
                node.appendChild(document.createElement("th"));
                node.appendChild(ctelt("th", "texttitle", baseTextName));
                node.appendChild(document.createElement("th"));
                node.appendChild(ctelt("th", "texttitle", newTextName));
                node.appendChild(document.createElement("th"));
                node.appendChild(ctelt("th", "texttitle", thirdTextName));
            }
            tdata = [tdata];

            var rows = [];
            var node2;

            /**
             * Adds two cells to the given row; if the given row corresponds to a real
             * line number (based on the line index tidx and the endpoint of the 
             * range in question tend), then the cells will contain the line number
             * and the line of text from textLines at position tidx (with the class of
             * the second cell set to the name of the change represented), and tidx + 1 will
             * be returned.  Otherwise, tidx is returned, and two empty cells are added
             * to the given row.
             */
            function addCells (row, tidx, tend, textLines, change) {
                if (tidx < tend) {
                    row.appendChild(telt("th", (tidx + 1).toString()));
                    row.appendChild(ctelt("td", change, textLines[tidx].replace(/\t/g, "\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0")));
                    return tidx + 1;
                } else {
                    row.appendChild(document.createElement("th"));
                    row.appendChild(celt("td", "empty"));
                    return tidx;
                }
            }

            function addCellsInline (row, tidx, tidx2, textLines, change) {
                row.appendChild(telt("th", tidx == null ? "" : (tidx + 1).toString()));
                row.appendChild(telt("th", tidx2 == null ? "" : (tidx2 + 1).toString()));
                row.appendChild(ctelt("td", change, textLines[tidx != null ? tidx : tidx2].replace(/\t/g, "\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0")));
            }

            for (var idx = 0; idx < opcodes.length; idx++) {
                code = opcodes[idx];
                change = code[0];
                var b = code[1];
                var be = code[2];
                var n = code[3];
                var ne = code[4];
                var rowcnt = Math.max(be - b, ne - n);
                var toprows = [];
                var botrows = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < rowcnt; i++) {
                    // jump ahead if we've alredy provided leading context or if this is the first range
                    if (contextSize && opcodes.length > 1 && ((idx > 0 && i == contextSize) || (idx == 0 && i == 0)) && change=="equal") {
                        var jump = rowcnt - ((idx == 0 ? 1 : 2) * contextSize);
                        if (jump > 1) {
                            toprows.push(node = document.createElement("tr"));

                            b += jump;
                            n += jump;
                            i += jump - 1;
                            node.appendChild(telt("th", "..."));
                            if (!inline) node.appendChild(ctelt("td", "skip", ""));
                            node.appendChild(telt("th", "..."));
                            node.appendChild(ctelt("td", "skip", ""));

                            // skip last lines if they're all equal
                            if (idx + 1 == opcodes.length) {
                                break;
                            } else {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    toprows.push(node = document.createElement("tr"));
                    if (inline) {
                        if (change == "insert") {
                            addCellsInline(node, null, n++, newTextLines, change);
                        } else if (change == "replace") {
                            botrows.push(node2 = document.createElement("tr"));
                            if (b < be) addCellsInline(node, b++, null, baseTextLines, "delete");
                            if (n < ne) addCellsInline(node2, null, n++, newTextLines, "insert");
                            if (n < ne) addCellsInline(node2, null, n++, thirdTextLines, "insert");

                        } else if (change == "delete") {
                            addCellsInline(node, b++, null, baseTextLines, change);
                        } else {
                            // equal
                            addCellsInline(node, b++, n++, baseTextLines, change);
                        }
                    } else {
                        b = addCells(node, b, be, baseTextLines, change);
                        n = addCells(node, n, ne, newTextLines, change);
                        n = addCells(node, n, ne, thirdTextLines, change);

                    }
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < toprows.length; i++) rows.push(toprows[i]);
                for (var i = 0; i < botrows.length; i++) rows.push(botrows[i]);
            }



            tdata.push(node = document.createElement("tbody"));
            for (var idx in rows) rows.hasOwnProperty(idx) && node.appendChild(rows[idx]);

            node = celt("table", "diff" + (inline ? " inlinediff" : ""));
            for (var idx in tdata) tdata.hasOwnProperty(idx) && node.appendChild(tdata[idx]);
            return node;
        }
    };
```

**difflib.js**

```
var __whitespace = {" ":true, "\t":true, "\n":true, "\f":true, "\r":true};

var difflib = {
    defaultJunkFunction: function (c) {
        return __whitespace.hasOwnProperty(c);
    },

    stripLinebreaks: function (str) { return str.replace(/^[\n\r]*|[\n\r]*$/g, ""); },

    stringAsLines: function (str) {
        var lfpos = str.indexOf("\n");
        var crpos = str.indexOf("\r");
        var linebreak = ((lfpos > -1 && crpos > -1) || crpos < 0) ? "\n" : "\r";

        var lines = str.split(linebreak);
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            lines[i] = difflib.stripLinebreaks(lines[i]);
        }

        return lines;
    },

    // iteration-based reduce implementation
    __reduce: function (func, list, initial) {
        if (initial != null) {
            var value = initial;
            var idx = 0;
        } else if (list) {
            var value = list[0];
            var idx = 1;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        for (; idx < list.length; idx++) {
            value = func(value, list[idx]);
        }

        return value;
    },

    // comparison function for sorting lists of numeric tuples
    __ntuplecomp: function (a, b) {
        var mlen = Math.max(a.length, b.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < mlen; i++) {
            if (a[i] < b[i]) return -1;
            if (a[i] > b[i]) return 1;
        }

        return a.length == b.length ? 0 : (a.length < b.length ? -1 : 1);
    },

    __calculate_ratio: function (matches, length) {
        return length ? 2.0 * matches / length : 1.0;
    },

    // returns a function that returns true if a key passed to the returned function
    // is in the dict (js object) provided to this function; replaces being able to
    // carry around dict.has_key in python...
    __isindict: function (dict) {
        return function (key) { return dict.hasOwnProperty(key); };
    },

    // replacement for python's dict.get function -- need easy default values
    __dictget: function (dict, key, defaultValue) {
        return dict.hasOwnProperty(key) ? dict[key] : defaultValue;
    },  

    SequenceMatcher: function (a, b, c, isjunk) {

        this.set_seqs = function (a, b, c, ) {


            this.set_seq1(a);
            this.set_seq2(b);
            this.set_seq3(c);


        }

        this.set_seq1 = function (a) {
            if (a == this.a) return;
            this.a = a;
            this.matching_blocks = this.opcodes = null;
        }

        this.set_seq2 = function (b) {
            console.log("Value in set ", b)

            if (b == this.b) return;
            this.b = b;
            this.matching_blocks = this.opcodes = this.fullbcount = null;
            this.__chain_b();
        }

        this.set_seq3 = function (c) {
            console.log("Value in set ", c)
            if (c == this.c) return;
            this.c = c;
            this.matching_blocks = this.opcodes = this.fullbcount = null;
            this.__chain_c();
        }

        this.__chain_c = function () {
            console.log("This is ", this.c)
            var c = this.c;
            var n = c.length;
            var c2j = this.c2j = {};
            var populardict = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                var celt = c[i];
                if (c2j.hasOwnProperty(celt)) {
                    var indices = c2j[elt];
                    if (n >= 200 && indices.length * 100 > n) {
                        populardict[celt] = 1;
                        delete c2j[celt];
                    } else {
                        indices.push(i);
                    }
                } else {
                    c2j[celt] = [i];
                }
            }

            for (var elt in populardict) {
                if (populardict.hasOwnProperty(elt)) {
                    delete c2j[elt];
                }
            }

            var isjunk = this.isjunk;
            var junkdict = {};
            if (isjunk) {
                for (var elt in populardict) {
                    if (populardict.hasOwnProperty(elt) && isjunk(elt)) {
                        junkdict[elt] = 1;
                        delete populardict[elt];
                    }
                }
                for (var elt in c2j) {
                    if (c2j.hasOwnProperty(elt) && isjunk(elt)) {
                        junkdict[elt] = 1;
                        delete c2j[elt];
                    }
                }
            }

            this.iscjunk = difflib.__isindict(junkdict);
            this.iscpopular = difflib.__isindict(populardict);
        }



        this.__chain_b = function () {
            var b = this.b;
            var n = b.length;
            var b2j = this.b2j = {};
            var populardict = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                var elt = b[i];
                if (b2j.hasOwnProperty(elt)) {
                    var indices = b2j[elt];
                    if (n >= 200 && indices.length * 100 > n) {
                        populardict[elt] = 1;
                        delete b2j[elt];
                    } else {
                        indices.push(i);
                    }
                } else {
                    b2j[elt] = [i];
                }
            }

            for (var elt in populardict) {
                if (populardict.hasOwnProperty(elt)) {
                    delete b2j[elt];
                }
            }

            var isjunk = this.isjunk;
            var junkdict = {};
            if (isjunk) {
                for (var elt in populardict) {
                    if (populardict.hasOwnProperty(elt) && isjunk(elt)) {
                        junkdict[elt] = 1;
                        delete populardict[elt];
                    }
                }
                for (var elt in b2j) {
                    if (b2j.hasOwnProperty(elt) && isjunk(elt)) {
                        junkdict[elt] = 1;
                        delete b2j[elt];
                    }
                }
            }

            this.isbjunk = difflib.__isindict(junkdict);
            this.isbpopular = difflib.__isindict(populardict);
        }

        this.find_longest_match = function (alo, ahi, blo, bhi) {
            var a = this.a;
            var b = this.b;
            var b2j = this.b2j;
            var isbjunk = this.isbjunk;
            var besti = alo;
            var bestj = blo;
            var bestsize = 0;
            var j = null;
            var k;

            var j2len = {};
            var nothing = [];
            for (var i = alo; i < ahi; i++) {
                var newj2len = {};
                var jdict = difflib.__dictget(b2j, a[i], nothing);
                for (var jkey in jdict) {
                    if (jdict.hasOwnProperty(jkey)) {
                        j = jdict[jkey];
                        if (j < blo) continue;
                        if (j >= bhi) break;
                        newj2len[j] = k = difflib.__dictget(j2len, j - 1, 0) + 1;
                        if (k > bestsize) {
                            besti = i - k + 1;
                            bestj = j - k + 1;
                            bestsize = k;
                        }
                    }
                }
                j2len = newj2len;
            }

            while (besti > alo && bestj > blo && !isbjunk(b[bestj - 1]) && a[besti - 1] == b[bestj - 1]) {
                besti--;
                bestj--;
                bestsize++;
            }

            while (besti + bestsize < ahi && bestj + bestsize < bhi &&
                    !isbjunk(b[bestj + bestsize]) &&
                    a[besti + bestsize] == b[bestj + bestsize]) {
                bestsize++;
            }

            while (besti > alo && bestj > blo && isbjunk(b[bestj - 1]) && a[besti - 1] == b[bestj - 1]) {
                besti--;
                bestj--;
                bestsize++;
            }

            while (besti + bestsize < ahi && bestj + bestsize < bhi && isbjunk(b[bestj + bestsize]) &&
                    a[besti + bestsize] == b[bestj + bestsize]) {
                bestsize++;
            }

            return [besti, bestj, bestsize];
        }

        this.get_matching_blocks = function () {
            if (this.matching_blocks != null) return this.matching_blocks;
            var la = this.a.length;
            var lb = this.b.length;

            var queue = [[0, la, 0, lb]];
            var matching_blocks = [];
            var alo, ahi, blo, bhi, qi, i, j, k, x;
            while (queue.length) {
                qi = queue.pop();
                alo = qi[0];
                ahi = qi[1];
                blo = qi[2];
                bhi = qi[3];
                x = this.find_longest_match(alo, ahi, blo, bhi);
                i = x[0];
                j = x[1];
                k = x[2];

                if (k) {
                    matching_blocks.push(x);
                    if (alo < i && blo < j)
                        queue.push([alo, i, blo, j]);
                    if (i+k < ahi && j+k < bhi)
                        queue.push([i + k, ahi, j + k, bhi]);
                }
            }

            matching_blocks.sort(difflib.__ntuplecomp);

            var i1 = 0, j1 = 0, k1 = 0, block = 0;
            var i2, j2, k2;
            var non_adjacent = [];
            for (var idx in matching_blocks) {
                if (matching_blocks.hasOwnProperty(idx)) {
                    block = matching_blocks[idx];
                    i2 = block[0];
                    j2 = block[1];
                    k2 = block[2];
                    if (i1 + k1 == i2 && j1 + k1 == j2) {
                        k1 += k2;
                    } else {
                        if (k1) non_adjacent.push([i1, j1, k1]);
                        i1 = i2;
                        j1 = j2;
                        k1 = k2;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (k1) non_adjacent.push([i1, j1, k1]);

            non_adjacent.push([la, lb, 0]);
            this.matching_blocks = non_adjacent;
            return this.matching_blocks;
        }

        this.get_opcodes = function () {
            if (this.opcodes != null) return this.opcodes;
            var i = 0;
            var j = 0;
            var answer = [];
            this.opcodes = answer;
            var block, ai, bj, size, tag;
            var blocks = this.get_matching_blocks();
            for (var idx in blocks) {
                if (blocks.hasOwnProperty(idx)) {
                    block = blocks[idx];
                    ai = block[0];
                    bj = block[1];
                    size = block[2];
                    tag = '';
                    if (i < ai && j < bj) {
                        tag = 'replace';
                    } else if (i < ai) {
                        tag = 'delete';
                    } else if (j < bj) {
                        tag = 'insert';
                    }
                    if (tag) answer.push([tag, i, ai, j, bj]);
                    i = ai + size;
                    j = bj + size;

                    if (size) answer.push(['equal', ai, i, bj, j]);
                }
            }

            return answer;
        }

        // this is a generator function in the python lib, which of course is not supported in javascript
        // the reimplementation builds up the grouped opcodes into a list in their entirety and returns that.
        this.get_grouped_opcodes = function (n) {
            if (!n) n = 3;
            var codes = this.get_opcodes();
            if (!codes) codes = [["equal", 0, 1, 0, 1]];
            var code, tag, i1, i2, j1, j2;
            if (codes[0][0] == 'equal') {
                code = codes[0];
                tag = code[0];
                i1 = code[1];
                i2 = code[2];
                j1 = code[3];
                j2 = code[4];
                codes[0] = [tag, Math.max(i1, i2 - n), i2, Math.max(j1, j2 - n), j2];
            }
            if (codes[codes.length - 1][0] == 'equal') {
                code = codes[codes.length - 1];
                tag = code[0];
                i1 = code[1];
                i2 = code[2];
                j1 = code[3];
                j2 = code[4];
                codes[codes.length - 1] = [tag, i1, Math.min(i2, i1 + n), j1, Math.min(j2, j1 + n)];
            }

            var nn = n + n;
            var group = [];
            var groups = [];
            for (var idx in codes) {
                if (codes.hasOwnProperty(idx)) {
                    code = codes[idx];
                    tag = code[0];
                    i1 = code[1];
                    i2 = code[2];
                    j1 = code[3];
                    j2 = code[4];
                    if (tag == 'equal' && i2 - i1 > nn) {
                        group.push([tag, i1, Math.min(i2, i1 + n), j1, Math.min(j2, j1 + n)]);
                        groups.push(group);
                        group = [];
                        i1 = Math.max(i1, i2-n);
                        j1 = Math.max(j1, j2-n);
                    }

                    group.push([tag, i1, i2, j1, j2]);
                }
            }

            if (group && !(group.length == 1 && group[0][0] == 'equal')) groups.push(group)

            return groups;
        }

        this.ratio = function () {
            matches = difflib.__reduce(
                            function (sum, triple) { return sum + triple[triple.length - 1]; },
                            this.get_matching_blocks(), 0);
            return difflib.__calculate_ratio(matches, this.a.length + this.b.length);
        }

        this.quick_ratio = function () {
            var fullbcount, elt;
            if (this.fullbcount == null) {
                this.fullbcount = fullbcount = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < this.b.length; i++) {
                    elt = this.b[i];
                    fullbcount[elt] = difflib.__dictget(fullbcount, elt, 0) + 1;
                }
            }
            fullbcount = this.fullbcount;

            var avail = {};
            var availhas = difflib.__isindict(avail);
            var matches = numb = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.a.length; i++) {
                elt = this.a[i];
                if (availhas(elt)) {
                    numb = avail[elt];
                } else {
                    numb = difflib.__dictget(fullbcount, elt, 0);
                }
                avail[elt] = numb - 1;
                if (numb > 0) matches++;
            }

            return difflib.__calculate_ratio(matches, this.a.length + this.b.length);
        }

        this.real_quick_ratio = function () {
            var la = this.a.length;
            var lb = this.b.length;
            return _calculate_ratio(Math.min(la, lb), la + lb);
        }

        this.isjunk = isjunk ? isjunk : difflib.defaultJunkFunction;
        this.a = this.b = null;
        this.set_seqs(a, b, c);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you post less code and more meaningful?

Comment: hi @MariosNikolaou just wanted to show what has been developed, I want 3 columns of text that are compared  and differences are shown. If you compare Base text vs new text that is working fine but I want same functionality for the 3rd text column

Comment: This is a lot for anyone to come in and wrap their heads around. Can you be more specific with the issue you're having? Judging by your initial scope In order to even get started helping you we would have to build your environment from scratch and spend time sifting through the lengthy process (some of which works and some of which doesn't ) to figure out what's happening.